# virtualbox win7 host debx64 guest networking issues

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Firstly, I had a stable VM working fine, then upgraded to the latest virtualbox edition and things went bad. First my .vdi crashed and could not be re-imported, so I downgraded to 4.1.4 that was working fine. I have duplicated the previous build from a deb amd64 business card iso.

The build went find with the guest fetching all required dependencies from the web no problem. However on restart I am having problems with the networking.

initially I could ssh into 192.168.56.112, however an apt-get returned network un-reachable. I could not ssh into the other IP's.
 So I did a little digging and deleted the 70-persistent-net.rules, rebooted and now a different permutation.

I can now ssh in via a dhcp address on adapter 3 (192.168.20.104), DNS seems to work fine with apt-get fetching.
 I can start a session on adapter 4 as soon as ssh requests Log in it terminates connection and will not re engage.
 The local IP's 192.168.56.x refuse connection as well.

After 3 days and multiple re-installs I still cant get this thing to do a basic config as I had it working before, any help is appreciated,
thx 
Art

my set up is a s follows,

```
adapter 1 => host-only (intel pro/1000 T server (82543GC)
Adapter 2 => NAT                  (intel pro/1000 T server (82543GC)
Adapter 3 =>  bridged            (intel pro/1000 T server (82543GC) //bridged to :  [Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:]
Adapter 4 =>  bridged            (intel pro/1000 T server (82543GC) // bridged to : [Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:]
```

70-persistent-net.rules

```
 # PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:a7:b9:b2", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

 # PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:ae:b0:9b", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x1af4:0x1000 (virtio_net)
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:1b:16:b4", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

 # PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:38:85:3a", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"[/code]
```

interfaces
     # The loopback network interface
     auto lo
     iface lo inet loopback

```
 # The primary network interface
 allow-hotplug eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.56.112
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.56.255

 allow-hotplug eth1
 iface eth1 inet dhcp

 allow-hotplug eth2
 iface eth2 inet dhcp

 allow-hotplug eth3
 iface eth3 inet static
 address 192.168.20.112
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.20.255
```

ifconfig -a

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ae:b0:9b
      inet addr:192.168.56.112  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feae:b09b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
      Interrupt:9 Base address:0xd240

 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1b:16:b4
      inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:16b4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1699 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1152 (1.1 KiB)

 eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a7:b9:b2
      inet addr:192.168.20.104  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea7:b9b2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:3284 (3.2 KiB)  TX bytes:1138 (1.1 KiB)

 eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:38:85:3a
      inet addr:192.168.20.112  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe38:853a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:67 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:10846 (10.5 KiB)  TX bytes:11466 (11.1 KiB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:560 (560.0 B)  TX bytes:560 (560.0 B)
```

ipconfig of host
     Windows IP Configuration

```
 Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : tosx500
 Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
 Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
 IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 10: 

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-6A-96-C7-8E
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 6:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Loopback Adapter
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-4C-4F-4F-50
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f139:e3f3:81f4:cb87%20(Preferred) 
 Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.203.135(Preferred) 
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
 DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 654442572
 DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-B2-35-4A-C8-0A-A9-0D-C5-90
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

 Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-F1-A1-04-70-B5
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

 Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8191SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-F1-A1-04-70-B5
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-0D-C5-90
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3593:4f1f:e8a5:9468%11(Preferred) 
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.103(Preferred) 
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::204:edff:fea9:39c%11
                                   192.168.20.1
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.1
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled



Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-4C-76
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

 Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a network bridge on Windows 7 in order to bridge the virtual NICs with the physical ones. It's a bit tricky to setup bridged networking with VirtualBox (VMware does this auto-magically). Think I just added both adapters to a bridge and enabled DHCP for it (if I remember correctly). Just in case: use WireShark to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on Windows host machine.

Configure your network adapter to

1) Allow the network adapter to wake the computer,

2) Allow a magic packet to wake the computer,

3) Allow IPV6

http://www.worldstart.com/dropped-internet-connection-in-sleep-mode/

Now, I can sleep and wake my machine, and both the guest and host will have networking, not just the host.